# UILabel sizeToFit - Adjust position on object below

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, sizetofit

I'm writing a screen that has multiple `UILabel` on it, each one below the other on the screen.
One of the labels has multiple lines and I've use `[myLabel sizeToFit]` along with `myLabel.numberOfLines = 0` to enable word wrapping and the label to stretch its height to fit all the text.
This works perfectly, however, all the other `UILabels` that I have positioned below this multi-line label in Interface Builder do not adjust their position in relation it. 
Is there a way to automatically get the other `UILabel` objects to adjust their position in relation to the stretched multi-line label?

Thanks

Brian

Comment: have you set the uiviewautoresizing properties of labels?

Comment: Hi. In Interface Builder I have checked the following attribute for the labels: "Autoresize Subviews". Is this what you are talking about or is there some other property?

Comment: check this out - http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling, this will help you in understanding the concept.

Comment: @rishi this is not what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From look around, the best solution is to actually implement this as a UITableView with static cells.

Answer (score 0):

I'd love to be proven wrong, but I think the only way to achieve this is to subclass the parent view of those UILabels and override [layoutSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) method. I had very similar problem some time ago, and this is what I ended up doing. I cannot find this class in my resources anymore, but I remember it was working pretty well even when the view was loaded from xib.